# I am in "danger of being blocked from asking any more", but I didn't do any bad

Tags: support, post-ban

So, I have now this warning.

The problem is that I didn't made any problematic activity on this site, and *I don't have any question in negative vote count*.

Anybody (mods?) could say, what is in the background?

P.S.: It is not a problem to me if you need to disclose "secret" info from my activity on this site, if it is needed to an explanation. It is also not a problem if you give me links to my deleted questions (which I can't see in my question list, but I can open if I get the link).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have three deleted, negatively scored questions:

- [Desktop PC with no moving parts](https://superuser.com/questions/873766/a-desktop-pc-without-moving-parts), -3, from February 2015
- [What is in C:\ccmcache](https://superuser.com/questions/786288/what-is-in-c-ccmcache), -1, from July 2014
- [Accidental deleting my mailbox, NSA help needed](https://superuser.com/questions/694031/accidental-deleting-my-mailbox-nsa-help-needed), -2, from December 2013

The 2nd question could have been answered; it seems you self-deleted it after only 5 minutes when it got negative votes. You could undelete that post, and I would actually answer it. The other posts are pretty old.

It does seem unlikely (and certainly unreasonable) to actually get question banned at this point. You have overall very positive contributions. Definitely make sure that your future questions are clearly written and maybe give the [How to Ask guide](/help/how-to-ask/) another read. In the unlikely event that you do become question banned, you can contact Stack Exchange to resolve it.

Comment: Thank you much! I undeleted my ccmcache question.

Comment: @nhinkle What should a user do with a question that has some negative votes, and it is not possible to edit it into better shape?  In other words, what should the user do if he realizes it was not a well-posed question?

Comment: @aparente001 - Why exactly is it not possible to edit into better shape?  I mean it received those negative votes for a reason.  I mean if it isn't on topic, that is one thing, but that solution is simple.  You make sure you ask good on topic questions.

Comment: @Ramhound, Sorry, I didn't mean in this case in particular, I'm trying to learn in general.

Comment: @aparente001 - I was speaking in general also.

Comment: @Ramhound The premise for my question is that editing a question into better shape is not possible.  This could be for a variety of reasons, for example, the question is not inherently suited to the SE model (e.g. just a matter of personal opinion or preference).  Since I'm asking in general terms, greater specificity isn't possible -- if I gave a specific reason, it wouldn't be general any more.  Does that make what I'm asking clearer?

Comment: @aparente001 - For questions that are not suited for SE those questions should remain deleted, then in the future questions that are not suited for SE, should not be asked in the future.  Unless you made a habit of asking really bad question that are not suited for SE, then the proposed and described situation in this question, really does not apply to you.